# Using Excel's Convert function along side cell referencing

Tags: excel, vba, function, output, concatenation

I am trying to make a user- defined function in VBA that will take in the input of a row. Then it will store each component I want of the excel sheet to a different variable with i being the row and 1,3,5,8,10 being the A,C,E,H,J columns. Value, being the only number, and Un1 Un2 Pre1 and Pre2 being units and prefixes. Then, I want to use those different variables within the Convert function, that is already built- in to excel, where I concatenate two of the variables I have defined so I am properly formatting my variables for the Convert function. Then, display the converted value and new units in a cell. I have not been able to figure out how to display the value and correct units into a cell yet, so I am trying to first do it with a message box. However, my code is giving me #Value! error when I run it as is and is not displaying a message box. Any advice on solving this issue? Sorry, I am new to VBA and coding so I hope this makes sense.

My Code right now:

```
Function Convert(i)

'Dimensioning the variable type of each variable
Dim value As Long
Dim pre1 As String
Dim un1 As String
Dim pre2 As String
Dim un2 As String
Dim Num As Double

'Selecting the desired cell in the chosen row
value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Select
pre1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Select
un1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Select
pre2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Select
un2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 10).Select

'using excel's built-in function, convert, to convert the value to a different unit
Num = Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(value, pre1 & un1, pre2 & un2)

MsgBox (Num & pre2 & un2)

End Function
```

Comment: first obvious problem is you should use `.value` instead of `.select` to store the value,pre1,un1, etc.. values

Comment: Thank you so much! I just changed that in my code and it is now correctly displaying the converted units and value. I tried to put that into a cell that has chosen row and column O, but I am getting a Value error again. How would I change this to ouptut both the converted number and new units in the i row O column cell? changed Num to be dimensioned as Variant and tried to use this code to put Num in the sheet : Sheets("Num2").Cells(i, 13).value = Num & pre2 & un2